# How to return the maximum over an Iterator of Results?

Tags: rust, iterator

Minimal example of the structure of my code ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=54fba956aa77b8206353846bd5db6f90)):

```
struct Error;

fn answer() -> Result<Option<i64>, Error> {
    (0..100_i64)
        .map(|i| -> Result<Option<i64>, Error> {
            let candidate = i * 7;
            if candidate <= 42 {
                Ok(Some(candidate))
            } else if candidate == 666 {
                Err(Error)
            } else {
                Ok(None)
            }
        })
        .max()
}
```

The goal is to take the maximum over the `i64` values, returning `Ok(None)` if none of the `Option`s contained a value, and immediately returning `Err(Error)` if *any* of the values were `Err(Error)`.

Of course this doesn't compile as is, because we can't take the `max()` over an iterable of `Result`s.

With a plain `for` loop, this would be possible (but inelegant):

```
fn answer() -> Result<Option<i64>, Error> {
    let items = (0..100_i64)
        .map(|i| -> Result<Option<i64>, Error> {
            let candidate = i * 7;
            if candidate <= 42 {
                Ok(Some(candidate))
            } else if candidate == 666 {
                Err(Error)
            } else {
                Ok(None)
            }
        });
    let mut max = None;
    for item in items {
        match item {
            Ok(candidate) => {
                // Conveniently, None < Some(_).
                max = std::cmp::max(max, candidate);
            }
            Err(Error) => {
                return Err(Error);
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(max)
}
```

Can it be done using chaining syntax and `?` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use an external crate, you can use `Iterator`'s [`try_fold` adaptor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold), which is only a little more verbose:

```
struct Error;

fn answer() -> Result<Option<i64>, Error> {
    (0..100_i64)
        .map(|i| -> Result<Option<i64>, Error> {
            let candidate = i * 7;
            if candidate <= 42 {
                Ok(Some(candidate))
            } else if candidate == 666 {
                Err(Error)
            } else {
                Ok(None)
            }
        })
        .try_fold(None, |prev, next| next.map(|ok| std::cmp::max(prev, ok)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Itertools::fold_ok` from the `itertools` crate:

```
fn answer() -> Result<Option<i64>, Error> {
    (0..100_i64)
        .map(|i| -> Result<Option<i64>, Error> {
            let candidate = i * 7;
            if candidate <= 42 {
                Ok(Some(candidate))
            } else if candidate == 666 {
                Err(Error)
            } else {
                Ok(None)
            }
        })
        .fold_ok(None, std::cmp::max) // Conveniently, None < Some(_)
}
```

I guess that the very existence of this function means that we'd need a `Result`-aware `max` function, like `max_ok`, in order to do this more cleanly.